# Usage of HMACs to verify the licensing during production

Tags: protocols, hmac, license-enforcement

We have a production that uses our software (put on a chip) and a requirement that we need to limit the amount of chips produced for each customer (so they need to buy a license) - so they can't produce more than allowed. The production is not controlled by us.

I'm trying to come up with a good enough protocol to ensure this.

We have:

- A device with unique device id, that cannot be changed by anyone and hardwired into the system.
- A usb dongle, with a secured memory that also allows some code execution. This will hold the license
- A software that is executed during production on PC (that has USB dongle installed) - it is used to put our software on a chip.

What I was thinking about:

- The device sends device ID to the software on PC, that sends device ID to the USB dongle.
- USB dongle computes HMAC with this device ID, and sends the digest back.
- The digest is saved alongside the software on chip.
- When software on chip is run, it computes the same HMAC and verifies they are equal. If they are not - refuse to run.
- The dongle will stop computing HMACs if license count is out.

I have a few questions to this:

- Is this a correct usage for HMACs?
- The problem with HMAC here is that it requires the same key to be present on USB dongle and device. This means that potentially an adversary can reverse engineer the key out of the device. Can we have the same concept, but assymetric protocol here, where the secret is stored only on USB dongle?

Comment: Licensing is primarily a legal topic, with technical license enforcement being secondary. To summarize it shortly: There is no 100% secure way to enforce licensing on a technical level. And even on a legal level, it may at times be better for business to send the customer a "gentle reminder" that they are "operating outside of the set licensing agreement", than immediate legal threats. From personal experience, dongles and other similar venues are often a PITA and tend to get circumvented in order to work in a more sane manner.

Comment: @MechMK1 Thanks. I understand in general this is more legal topic - but I want to try our best to come up with the technical solution that protects us as much as possible. Of course it is never 100% protection, but to make it "hard" to hack is good enough

Comment: Making it "hard to hack" usually means "hard to use" and is generally a bad approach. A legal, contractual solution is generally the best approach.

Comment: @Archeg I agree with ThoriumBR's conclusion. I would not spend too much time trying to engineer a "hard to crack" system, and instead just a "good enough" system.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I understand the point, however, legal enforcement is basically non-existant for manufacturing electronics. Most countries where the electronics is manufactured provide minumum or even no legal coverage. One could argue that the production should be moved to a coutry with such a coverage, but we are selling the software for the chip, and in no control where the client manufactures